# Connection to dc in telegram api java

Tags: java, websocket, telegram, mtproto

I try to connect to telegram using [java telegram api](https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-api). And on this code it throws exception

```
    private static void createApi() throws IOException {
    apiState = new ApiStorage(true);
    api = new TelegramApi(apiState, new AppInfo(API_ID, "console", "2", "1", "en"), new ApiCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onAuthCancelled(TelegramApi api) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdatesInvalidated(TelegramApi api) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(TLAbsUpdates updates) {
        }
    });
}
```

It's what I see in console:

```
TelegramApi#1001:Phase 0 in 1 ms
TelegramApi#1001:Phase 1 in 119 ms
TelegramApi#1001:Timeout Iteration
TelegramApi#1001:Connection iteration
TelegramApi#1001:#1: waitForDc
TelegramApi#1001:#1: Creating proto for dc
TelegramApi#1001:#1: Creating key
TelegramApi#1001:Phase 2 in 7 ms
TelegramApi#1001:Sender iteration
TelegramApi#1001:Phase 3 in 7 ms
api#1001#Uploader:UploadFileThread iteration
api#1001#Uploader:UploadFileThread iteration
api#1001#Uploader:UploadFileThread iteration
api#1001#Downloader:DownloadFileThread iteration
api#1001#Downloader:DownloadFileThread iteration
api#1001#Downloader:DownloadFileThread iteration
api#1001#Uploader:UploadFileThread iteration
api#1001#Downloader:DownloadFileThread iteration
TransportRate:Transport: #1 149.154.167.40:443 #1.0
TransportRate:tryConnection #1
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: connect
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that you can not connect to the provided address (149.154.167.40:443). Maybe is wrong, outdated, or unnaccesible from your current location.

Some Datat Center (DC) addresses:
https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/master/Telegram/SourceFiles/config.h#L212

Take a look to these methods too: [help.getConfig](https://core.telegram.org/method/help.getConfig) and 
[help.getNearestDc](https://core.telegram.org/method/help.getNearestDc).